# Autoencoder and Neural Network Overfitting in terms of parameter number?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, n-gram, autoencoder

I have `1100` sequences for 2 classes. Of them `400` are from one `class 1` and `700` are from `class 2`. I have used an one hidden layer auto-encoder of `2` neurons to capture my features. My initial features are tri-grams for each sequences. So, for each sequence I have `6860` tri-grams. As a result most of my input vectors are sparse vectors.

Now, if I calculate the parameters for this network, I have

```
6860 * 2 = 13720 paramters (1st layer)
2 * 6860 = 13720 parameters (2nd layer)
-----------------------------------------
           27440 parameters (in total)
```

Now, that is way too many parameters in comparison to my number of data points. Hence, I have used a dropout value of `0.98`, on `layer 1->hidden layer` as well as `hidden layer->output layer` which makes the number of parameters `13720 * 0.02 =  274` on each layer and in total `548` parameters.

Now, after training, I tried the encoder on my test data of `500` sequences, and extracted the hidden layer of 2 dimensional data. Then I use that data on another 5 neuron single hidden layer neural network to classify. My results are really good in that I am getting around `90%` accuracy.

My question is am I overfitting in my autoencoder? Am I overfitting by using another neural network? I am worried about my low number of data points. Does my use of dropout seem sensible?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the hidden layer size with dropouts turned off until you perfectly fit the data, then using that hidden layer size you can start increasing the dropouts parameter to get a feel for how the model behaves.

Also you may want to add an alpha parameter to tune the weight updates.

And you may have luck aggregating some of your parameters together.